# Banshee is still in the sound menu after unistalling

Tags: banshee, indicator-sound

Using 11.04 I uninstalled Banshee from the Software Center, restarted the system but still it's visible in the sound menu. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to remove it and blacklist it in Dconf.

1. Install `dconf-tools` package
2. Execute `dconf-editor` from Terminal or using Alt+F2
3. In the left menu, select apps>indicators>sound
4. You should see `banshee` in `interested-media-players`. Remove it: set the key to `[]` (or keep just players you are interested in)
5. To make things future-proof, you can add Banshee to `blacklisted-media-players`

The result should look like this: [image: dconf-editor indicators sound]

Comment: haha you posted the same thing as me while I was typing :P

Answer (score 1):

The values for applications that show up in the sound indicator are found in a dconf entry.
To remove them:

- install dconf-tools
- open dconf-editor
- edit the entry "interested-media-players" and remove banshee

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check under .cache/indicators/ for a "sound" folder, delete it if it is there and log out/in.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want some adventure, u can erase on synaptic ubuntu-desktop package. The only problem u might face with is that the sound ibcon will disappear too. It's a risc, but for me, as i use alsamixer for sound control, i don't need ubuntu-desktop. So, i do not know if it is your case though.

Comment: I recommend not doing that :-)

Comment: And why is that? That will crash something?

Comment: I don't think it will, but some software has ubuntu-desktop as a dependency, so it **might** cause some problems in the future.

Comment: Ok, thnx. I will keep that in mind in the future. But, it was the only way for me to put skype working well. Skype doesn't work well with pulseaudio. And everything works fine since then. :D