# Banshee sound menu integration in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, banshee, rhythmbox, indicator-sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove players I don't use from the sound indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12867/how-do-i-remove-players-i-dont-use-from-the-sound-indicator)

So since they decided to switch back to Rhythmbox as the default music player, Rhythmbox turned out to be the default in the sound menu as well.

The only problem is that I don't really use Rhythmbox, and have everything the way I want to in Banshee already. So I set my default music player to Banshee, but the default in the sound menu is still shown as Rhythmbox.

Okay. Banshee shows up when I manually start it, but it turns out that Rhythmbox is still sitting at the top there. It's a bit annoying, since I never click on it anyway...

[image: Two music players?]

So is there a way to get Banshee back as the default in the sound menu?

Comment: Have you tried removing the Rythmbox package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Players supporting mpris2 will initially be listed in the sound menu in order of install & use, this can also be seen in the key in gsettings/dconf-editor - `com.canonical.indicator.sound interested-media-players`

If deciding to have more than one supported player installed & wishing to order differently then just edit that key to reflect order desired. Changes will be seen after a log out/in

Answer (score 0):

You can remove and blacklist it by `Dconf Editor`.

1. Install `Dconf Editor` by command `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Launch `dconf-editor`
3. Navigate to `apps/indicators/sounds`, remove 'rhythmbox' from the value of 'interested-media-player'.
4. add 'rhythmbox' as value of 'blacklisted-media-players' to blacklist it.

See [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48218/banshee-is-still-in-the-sound-menu-after-unistalling)

Comment: Hmm. Can't seem to find a 'sound' entry in apps/indicator/. 
I just went with the above answer and used com/canonical/indicator/sound.